# model-driven dynamic object graphs - datasource or custom approach?

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I've got some fundamental questions about which path to choose with smartGWT.
I'm playing around with it for some time already and got used to the widget stuff so far. There are problems (esp. with browsers), but who got none...

I've got a custom objects retreival mechanism, with a local descriptor/object cache and resolver that triggers the standard gwt-rpc-async scheme. 
I'm exchanging objects with IDs and properties, rather than datasets. They are represented as trees/networks already in the client. So, whenever I explore the graph/tree, new objects are loaded. Or, if already present in cache, reused (this avoids entity recursion).

To display trees and lists, I didn't use datasource. I've managed to manually create my own **Tree** objects, update nodes/children when something is loaded, set properties etc. So far this works, dynamically. I'm setting a **Tree** to a **TreeGrid** with **setData()**, and most changes in the Tree (add, addList, remove etc.) are reflected instantly in the View.

But here problems begin. I like the model-driven approach, where the model (Tree) does something with data/objects (changes properties, adds/removes nodes) and notifies the view (TreeGrid). Only the model knows what and when to do with data. But there are no/few methods included, it's all under the hood (JavaScript). I could write my own EventHandler and connect to TreeGrid (which in turn has methods like **refreshRow()** etc.). But i feel uneasy doing this with smartGWT because of unknown implications, memory leaks and such.

To me, it seems that view and model are too coupled in smartGWT. I'm working with a model for my object graphs, which would be reusable for *different* kinds of views (TreeGrid, ListGrid, even custom Canvases), and i don't know which will be showing my data. For lists, i simply use the children of my root node, for trees i use the whole model.

It seems that most of smartGWT is really built for DataSources. Why didn't use it? 
**Object graphs** are heterogeneous. Unpredictable. There may be collections of homogeneous stuff, but then again me be not. It's not comparable to distinct database resultsets. Objects fields are analysed on the client already by their descriptors (classes). Moreover, i use *interfaces*: an object property can be accessed directly, or by resolving an interface. That means "ITimeObject.time" would be resolved to an implementing property in "TelephoneCall.starTime". I don't know how to create such a DataSource... ?

It even gets worse: I have role and permission based access to objects. That means a certain user may see all fields, another one only parts.

Once I created the resolver and the model which should be built for a view (dynamically) I would want to use it everywhere in the code, rather than creating "mapping" for each call/view. Everything is built on-the-fly, in the user interface I don't know anything about concrete types, objects etc. The descriptions all come from the backend.

**OK**. Now the questions :) Just needed to clarify a lot of stuff here.
I would need a hint which path to choose from here.

1. Go on. Use own model/view.

   1a. Will I be able to implement all features like filtering, search, editing/validation, that are available with datasources?

   1b. How do I implement model->view notification manually? Something like nodeUpdated(TreeNode node, boolean childrenToo) without side-effects, e.g. when closing a view, setting new model, destroying canvas

   1c. There's datasource everywhere, forms, editors etc. Would there be ways to plug my own model into them?
2. Hang on. All possible with DataSource.

   2a. How do I then create datasources in the client on the fly (using my existing model) that are adaptive and sensitive to what's retrieved and to what's intended to be displayed. Having a view description (fields) and "accepted sources" I can explore an object graph.

   2b. Is it possible to avoid the "parent ID" scheme? That means it rather goes top-down beginning with a known object. It also can contain identical objects multiple times in lists, or be child of different parents.

---

sorry for the lengthy description. i've got no concrete code questions to post a.t.m., because I'm not yet at editing & such, just display. I wanted to analyse if i should go on from here, because i've run into limitations of the Tree/TreeGrid communication.

thanks for your thoughts :)

Comment: Probably this is not right place for the question. This might get better traction at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks @SSR, maybe you're right. i'm new to this stackexchange thing (though not as a reader), didn't know that "area" exists. can i move the topic, or will anybody be annoyed if do a double post? :)

Comment: I dont think anybody will be annoyed if it is double posted.